# Preventing Unity from writing to the registry?

Tags: unity, windows

I see that Unity automatically writes some info to registry when it launches the game. Several people have this problem too:

[Preventing Unity from writing to the registry.](https://forum.unity.com/threads/preventing-unity-from-writing-to-the-registry.125411/)

[How to disable writing to Windows registry?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/976024/how-to-disable-writing-to-windows-registry.html)

It seems several years have passed but I still can't find how to prevent Unity from writing to registry. I just want to make Unity save & load settings from file in document folder.

Comment: If Unity doesn't support that in the documentation, then the only solution would be to ask the Unity developers directly. Keep in mind that doing things that aren't supported could potentially violate Unity's ToS. I'm not sure if messing with the registry does, but always worth being aware.